Transponer valores de una columna "tecnología" usando pivot_table
Tengo una tabla en este formato y utilizando pandas quiero transponer el valor de tech en distintas columnas.

Quedando algo así

Intente con este codigo pero no me da el resultado deseado:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Sitio': ['Sitio1', 'Sitio1', 'Sitio1', 'Sitio2', 'Sitio2', 'Sitio2', 'Sitio3', 'Sitio3', 'Sitio3'],
    'ID': ['ID0001', 'ID0001', 'ID0001', 'ID0002', 'ID0002', 'ID0002', 'ID0003', 'ID0003', 'ID0003'],
    'Tech': ['3G', 'LTE', '5G', '3G', 'LTE', '5G', '3G', 'LTE', '']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df2 = df.pivot_table(index=['Sitio', 'ID'], columns='Tech', values='Tech').reset_index()
print(df2)


Buen día,
Puedes primero crear una columna adicional para identificar el número de tecnología, luego hacer pivot y por último renombrar las columnas con los nombres que desees.
Ejemplo completo:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Sitio': ['Sitio1', 'Sitio1', 'Sitio1', 'Sitio2', 'Sitio2', 'Sitio2', 'Sitio3', 'Sitio3', 'Sitio3'],
    'ID': ['ID0001', 'ID0001', 'ID0001', 'ID0002', 'ID0002', 'ID0002', 'ID0003', 'ID0003', 'ID0003'],
    'Tech': ['3G', 'LTE', '5G', '3G', 'LTE', '5G', '3G', 'LTE', '']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#print(df)

# Agregar un acumulador para diferenciar las columnas
df['TechNum'] = df.groupby(['Sitio', 'ID']).cumcount() + 1
#print(df)

# Hacer pivot con Sitio e ID
# Utilizamos reset_index para inicializar el número de filas
df = df.pivot_table(index=['Sitio', 'ID'], columns='TechNum', values='Tech', aggfunc='first').reset_index()
#print(df)

# Renombrar las columnas
df.columns = ['Sitio', 'ID', 'Tech1', 'Tech2', 'Tech3']

print(df)

Esto devuelve:
    Sitio      ID Tech1 Tech2 Tech3
0  Sitio1  ID0001    3G   LTE    5G
1  Sitio2  ID0002    3G   LTE    5G
2  Sitio3  ID0003    3G   LTE      

Dejé 3 print comentados para que puedas probar lo que devuelve cada línea y así entender mejor el proceso.
